# find infinity values and replace with maximum per vector in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following array with shape `(3, 5)` :

```
array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, inf, 5],
                    [10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
                    [4, inf, 2, 6, inf]])
```

Now I want to find the infinity values per vector and replace them with the maximum of that vector, with a lower limit of 1.

So the output for this example shoud be:

```
array_solved = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 5, 5],
                    [10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
                    [4, 6, 2, 6, 6]])
```

I could do this by looping over every vector of the array and apply:

```
idx_inf = np.isinf(array_vector)
max_value = np.max(np.append(array_vector[~idx_inf], 1.0))
array_vector[idx_inf] = max_value
```

But I guess there is a faster way.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, np.inf, 5],
                    [10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
                    [4, np.inf, 2, 6, np.inf]])

n, m = array.shape
array[np.isinf(array)] = -np.inf
mx_array = np.repeat(np.max(array, axis=1), m).reshape(n, m)
ind = np.where(np.isinf(array))
array[ind] = mx_array[ind]
```

Output `array`:

```py
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  5.],
       [10.,  9.,  8.,  7.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  6.,  2.,  6.,  6.]])
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to first convert `inf`s to `NaN`s with [`np.isinf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) masking and then `NaN`s to max values of rows with [`np.nanmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html):

```
array[np.isinf(array)] = np.nan
array[np.isnan(array)] = np.nanmax(array, axis=1)
```

to get

```
>>> array

array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  5.],
       [10.,  9.,  8.,  7.,  6.],
       [ 4., 10.,  2.,  6.,  6.]])
```